# Java. Action listener for JMenu

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenu

How can I add action listener for `JMenu` (not for `JMenuItem`)? I want to open new window on clicking this menu. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html): Take a look at the section named ***Methods inherited from class javax.swing.AbstractButton***

Comment: Have u tried with add mouse listener. ?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#addMenuListener(javax.swing.event.MenuListener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one and you can add an action listener to the JMenu.

```
menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Execute when JMenu is pressed
        System.out.println("You clicked the JMenu");
    }
});
```

Comment: Krishna, thank you! I got it.

Comment: This doesn't work.